# Is the "limit" of this filtration the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Define the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ on $[0,1]$ via
$$
\mathcal{F}_n := \sigma\Big(\big[k 2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}\big) \mid k = 0, 1, \dotsc, 2^{n}-1 \Big).
$$
Is it true that the "limit" of this filtration is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, i.e.,
$$
\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{F}_n = \mathcal{B}([0,1])~~?
$$

The direction $\subseteq$ seems obvious to me, but I cannot show the other direction.

Comment: Note that the "limit" of a filtration $\{\mathcal F_n\}$ is not given by $\bigcup_n\mathcal F_n$ since this is not usually a $\sigma$-field. We do often call the $\sigma$-field *generated* by this set $\mathcal F_\infty$, though, since it is the most natural way to define a limiting $\sigma$-field. In your case, yes, $\mathcal F_\infty$ is the Borel $\sigma$-field.

Comment: Could you give a counterexample? Since $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a filtration, $\bigcup_{n \le N} \mathcal{F}_n = \mathcal{F}_N$ is a $\sigma$-field for each $N.$ Why is $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{F}_n$ not a $\sigma$-field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $A=[0,1/3)$ : we have $A\notin \mathcal{F}_n$ for all $n$, but $A\in \mathcal{B}([0,1])$.

A true statement is :
$$\mathcal{B}([0,1])=\sigma\bigg(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left\{[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}) \mid k=0,1,\dotsc,2^n-1\right\}\bigg).$$